# How to index azure blob custom metadata fields to Azure search

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-blob-storage

I was trying to index the blob content to Azure search. I added blob content to the search index through blob indexer.

I am using MongoDB to store the uploaded file information along with blob path. We have to add some tags to the file which were stored in MongoDB. Now I want to add these tags into Azure search for that file along with file content.

The problem I am facing is,

**Problem 1:** To maintain the uniqueness(search key field) between MongoDB record and blob indexer. Initially, I want to use the metadata_storage_path from blob indexer and the base64 encoded blob path which I was stored in MongoDB. But the problem is it never matches the metadata_storage_path and base64 encoded blob path from my node.js.

**Problem 2:** TO solve the Problem 1, I came into another approach to store my MongoDB file id(FID) as a custom metadata field to the blob to get the uniqueness(search key field) for search index and mongoDB record. The problem here how can I map the custom metadata field to key field? I am not able to index the blob custom metadata fields.

In both the scenarios I am not able to achieve the expected results. How can I achieve the search index key field between MongoDB and Azure blob?

Comment: just add the blob path in the mongodb document ?

Comment: @Thomas My Problem 1 explains the same. I added the blob path and while associating the base64 encoded blob path it is never same as metadata_storage_path

Comment: Is the stored blob path in MongoDB base64 encoded or is it in plain text?
Does your node.js encoding function match any option here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-indexer-field-mappings#base64details)?

Comment: It was stored as plain text.

Comment: You can also use [field mappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-indexer-field-mappings) to "fork" the `metadata_storage_path` field into a new encoded field in your index.

Comment: And, should you want to index blob custom metadata for this or any other scenario, add a corresponding field to your index and it will be indexed. For example, if your blobs have a custom metadata field called `fid`, add a `fid` field to your index and the indexer will index your blobs' metadata as you expect.

Comment: @Eugene Shvets  Thankyou, It's worked. I am trying to map explicitly through fieldMapping, that was the problem. I removed that field Mapping now. Now it's working as expected. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use base64 encoded blob path as the document key, which you can get in both indexers by using base64 field mapping. Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-indexer-field-mappings#base64EncodeFunction for all the options to match your node.js encoding function.